# How do I decoding UTF-8 characters in QRcode?

Tags: android, apache-flex, zxing, qr-code

use ZXing V2.2

code:
      (  com\google\zxing\qrcode\decoder )

```
  function decodeByteSegment(){ ... result.Append(readBytes); }
```

change to

```
  function decodeByteSegment(){ 
    .....
    var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
for (var k:int=0;k<readBytes.length;k++) { ba.writeByte(readBytes[k]); }
ba.position = 0;
result.Append(ba.readMultiByte(ba.length,encoding));
 }
```

for this example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff9um.png

scan result is "䭖1357" but it's should be "中文12345678" !!

How do I decoding UTF-8 characters in QRcode?